# Axis 2 web ervice stops when I try to connect the database

Tags: java, android, webserver

I have a webserver created using Axis2. my client is Android App. the webservice connects to the database. but the webservice gets stopped automatically.

The code to connect to the database`public class Connect {
    public Connection Connection() {

```
    Connection conn = null;


    try {
        String userName = "Admin";
        String password = "admin";
        //String url = "jdbc:mysql://mysql.cs.nott.ac.uk:3306/svp01m";
        String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost/tests";
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
        conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, userName, password);

        System.out.println ("\n Database connection established");

    } catch (Exception e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
        System.err.println("\n Cannot connect to database server");
        System.exit(0);
    }

    return conn;
}
```

}`

The code calling from webservice is

```
public class Calculate
```

{

```
public boolean populateLeagues(String username, String password){

    try {
        /*Create object of the Connect class*/
        Connect connect = new Connect();
        /* calling the Connection method of Connect class to establish a database connection*/
        Connection conn = connect.Connection();

        java.sql.PreparedStatement preparedStatement = null;
        /* Creating a query to be executed with prepared statement*/
        String query = "select name from users where name=?";

        preparedStatement = conn.prepareStatement(query);
        /*substitutes the value for ? in the prepared Statement */
        preparedStatement.setString(1, username);
        /* Result set to capture the results of the query*/
        ResultSet rs = preparedStatement.executeQuery();

        boolean empty = true;
        while (rs.next()) {
            empty=false;
            System.err.println("\n User Name exists  \n");
            return true;
        }

        if(empty)
        {
            System.out.println("\n the userame does not exists");
            return false;
        }
        rs.close();
        conn.close();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        //e.printStackTrace();
         System.err.println ("Cannot connect to database server");
         System.exit(0);
    }
    return true;

}
```

the exception i get is

> java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
>       at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1680)
>       at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1526)
>       at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
>       at java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source)
>       at org.web.backend.calculate.Connect.Connection(Connect.java:17)
>       at org.web.backend.calculate.Calculate.populateLeagues(Calculate.java:17)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
>       at org.apache.axis2.rpc.receivers.RPCUtil.invokeServiceClass(RPCUtil.java:194)
>       at org.apache.axis2.rpc.receivers.RPCMessageReceiver.invokeBusinessLogic(RPCMessageReceiver.java:102)
>       at org.apache.axis2.receivers.AbstractInOutMessageReceiver.invokeBusinessLogic(AbstractInOutMessageReceiver.java:40)
>       at org.apache.axis2.receivers.AbstractMessageReceiver.receive(AbstractMessageReceiver.java:100)
>       at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.receive(AxisEngine.java:176)
>       at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.HTTPTransportUtils.processHTTPPostRequest(HTTPTransportUtils.java:275)
>       at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.AxisServlet.doPost(AxisServlet.java:133)
>       at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:637)
>       at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
>       at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
>       at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:293)
>       at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:859)
>       at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:602)
>       at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:489)
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

Cannot connect to database server

Comment: I hope this is the code that is executed on the server, and not on the Android client... right?

Comment: yes it's executed on the server

Comment: you are missing your `com.mysql.jdbc.Driver` on your server as far as I can see from your logs.

Comment: I added the them in the java Build path of the server... is this the correct way to add ?

Comment: Can anyone help please.. I am little desperate to get this working..

Comment: you `.jar`should probably be put in `tomcat/lib` or `jboss/lib` depending on what you are using..

Comment: Tried this , still the same error.. When the code tries to open a new db connection the we service stops